# Set IDEA to make Java-based suggestions?

Tags: intellij-idea

IDEA suggests (among other things) name for some method or class member and so on.

How can I set it to propose name in the spirit of Java language?

For example, I want to create a class member of type `MyClass` and I want IDEA to propose the name `mMyClass`, instead of `myClass` (which is default behaviour)?

PS. I use Java as part of Android development. Here is [Android Code Style](http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html#follow-field-naming-conventions).

Comment: I feel like prefixing "m" is actually more in the spirit of C than Java, but I might be alone on that...

Comment: @T045T Android coding. Look at my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
settings > code style > java > code generation > naming
```

but putting m at the front for a method goes against [convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html). It sounds like a borked version of hungarian notation.

Comment: Look at my edit. It's Android coding and 'm' is in accordance to its code style.

Comment: doesn't android studio autmatically set that as the default ? The point being use android studio (based on intellij) for android dev, not intellij. http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html

Comment: I am still not using Android Studio. Have been using IDEA for years and Studio seems to be in Beta still. It's version number indicated that as well.

Comment: yeah its pretty stable though I think.

Comment: Are you Android developer? Do you use it in production environment? I am monitoring IDEA's announcements, but to be frank, I haven't seen their recommendation to migrate from IDEA to AS.